# Updating to Swift 2.0 'map' is unavailable: call the 'map()' method on the sequence

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

Code is from a github control called ZLBalancedFlowLayout. ([link](https://github.com/zhxnlai/ZLBalancedFlowLayout)). I've been trying to update to Swift 2.0 but I get this error " 'map' is unavailable: call the 'map()' method on the sequence". Any advice would be helpful. Thank you in advance.

```
 private func collectionView(collectionView:UICollectionView, framesForItemsInSection section:Int, inout updateContentSize contentSize:CGSize) -> ([CGRect], [CGFloat]) {

    let maxWidth = Float(scrollDirection == .Vertical ? contentSize.width : contentSize.height),
    widths = map(0..<collectionView.numberOfItemsInSection(section), {(item: Int) -> Float in
        let itemSize = self.sizeForItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: item, inSection: section)),
        ratio = self.scrollDirection == .Vertical ?
            itemSize.width/itemSize.height :
            itemSize.height/itemSize.width
        return min(Float(ratio*self.rowHeight), Float(maxWidth))
    })
```

Answer (score 6):

In Swift 2 `map` is not a global function anymore, it's a method that you call *on the sequence*.

Instead of:

```
let result = map(array, closure)
```

Do:

```
let result = array.map(closure)
```

The same concept also applies to other sequence methods like `enumerate`, `split`, etc.

Comment: according to all responses I changed it to widths = (0..<collectionView.numberOfItemsInSection(section)).map({(item: Int) -> Float in with no errors.. Thank you all..

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 2 many functions have been changed from

```
functionName(object, action)
```

to

```
object.functionName(action)
```